# Recompile and run red5 server error Bootstrap exception: null

Tags: red5

Red5 source file download is complete, the programming is successful, but the copy "F:\javaweb\red5-server\target\red5-server-1.0.8-theSNAPSHOT.jar"
To red5 server directory, replacing "red5-server.Jar" error, error information is as follows:

中文语言

我下载了red5源文件下载完整，编程成功，但复制F:\javaweb\red5-server\target\red5-server-1.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
到red5-server目录下，替换成red5-server.jar报错，错误信息如下代码：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xRYD.png)

```
 [INFO] [main] org.red5.spring.Red5ApplicationContext - Closing ApplicationContex
    t 'red5.common': startup date [Sun May 22 19:20:25 GMT+08:00 2016]; parent: org.
    springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@cb644e
    [INFO] [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter
    - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
    [INFO] [main] org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter
    - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
    [INFO] [main] org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean - Stopp
    ing JMX connector server: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer@7a419da
    4
    [INFO] [main] org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean - Unreg
    istering JMX-exposed beans
    [INFO] [main] org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean - Unexport
    ing RMI registry
    [INFO] [main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_C
    LUSTERED shutting down.
    [INFO] [main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_C
    LUSTERED paused.
    [INFO] [main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_C
    LUSTERED shutdown complete.
    Bootstrap exception: null
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.bootStrap(Bootstrap.java:122)
            at org.red5.server.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:50)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
    ng bean with name 'context.loader' defined in class path resource [red5.xml]: Er
    ror setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWr
    itablePropertyException: Invalid property 'useShutdownHook' of bean class [org.r
    ed5.server.ContextLoader]: Bean property 'useShutdownHook' is not writable or ha
    s an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the retu
    rn type of the getter?
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
    ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
    y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
    an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
    (AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
    preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
    BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
    h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
            at org.red5.server.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:64)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid prope
    rty 'useShutdownHook' of bean class [org.red5.server.ContextLoader]: Bean proper
    ty 'useShutdownHook' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the p
    arameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
            at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyEx
    ception(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
            at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropert
    yValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
            at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropert
    yValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
            at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(
    AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
            at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(
    AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
    Factory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
            ... 17 more
    Bootstrap exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the property **useShutdownHook** from the ContextLoader bean.

Comment: Thank you, but still won't do

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved, thank you!I downloaded the latest red5 1.08 extract the jar on the 1.07 version, so we will go wrong!Solution: git rollbackcopied version to 1.07  or from "red5-server\SRC\main\server" file inside say 1.08 server.